# how to merge multiple arrays to one array in masm32

Tags: arrays, assembly, x86, masm32

I want to concatenate array1 array2 ... to one array
how  is fast way:

```
.data
array1      db  0CFh, 0C2h, 0ABh, 01Bh, 0C1h, 007h, 0F7h, 06Dh, 0DAh, 0F2h, 0DCh, 03Ch....; about 2000 dup
...
array2      db  0BFh, 03Dh, 087h, 0F1h, 0A6h, 097h, 0A6h, 05Bh, 010h, 0F2h, 051h, 05Eh ...

.data ?
arrayOut        dd    ?
.code
        invoke crt_memcpy, array, addr array1, sizeof array1
        mov ecx, [arrayOut]
        add ecx,sizeof array1
        invoke crt_memcpy,dword ptr[ecx], addr array2, sizeof array2    ???
```

I also try use code as below:

```
        mov eax, 0                             
        mov ecx, sizeof array1 *2   
        mov edi, 0
        mov esi, 0
L1:
        mov al, [array1 + esi * TYPE BYTE]      
        movsx eax, al    
        mov arrayOut[esi], eax 
        cmp ecx,esi
        jbe GoOnNext
        inc esi     
        loop L1
GoOnNext:
        mov ecx, sizeof array2 *2
        mov edi,0
L2:                       
        mov bl, [array2 + edi * TYPE BYTE]    
        movsx ebx, bl   
        mov arrayOut[esi], ebx   
        cmp ecx,edi
        jbe nextstep
        inc esi          
        add edi,1
        loop L2
nextstep:
        mov eax, arrayOut
```

But if the size of the array is large, I get the wrong result。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But if the size of the array is large, I get the wrong result

With a declaration like `arrayOut dd ?`, there's not enough room to copy to! Based on the mention that both arrays contain about 2000 bytes, you could make this something like:

```
arrayOut db 4096 dup ?
```

Next is a basic way to copy a block of memory:

```
cld                         ; Makes the addresses ESI and EDI increment
mov  edi, OFFSET arrayOut   ; Destination
mov  esi, OFFSET array1     ; Source
mov  ecx, SIZEOF array1     ; Count
rep movsb
```

In order to concatenate, you then copy the second array **but you don't modify the value in the destination register EDI**. This way the second copy continues where the first copy left off.

```
mov  esi, OFFSET array2     ; Source
mov  ecx, SIZEOF array2     ; Count
rep movsb
```